# How to pass the "dark zombie garage" in Half-Life 2: Episode One?

Tags: achievements, half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-one

In *Half-Life 2: Episode One*, the last underground level is where Gordon and Alyx find an unpowered elevator, look around for a switch to power it on, and then try to survive the zombie onslaught while waiting the elevator to arrive.

In my previous playthroughs, I always struggled on this part, and could only survive after a few tries. (Damn you, massive zombie horde! Damn you, zombies carrying a grenade! Damn you, slow elevator that takes forever! Damn you, flashlight that doesn't have enough battery!)

Now that [achievements were added to the PC version](http://store.steampowered.com/news/3873/), I'm replaying this game, and I thought about [The One Free Bullet](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/HL2:EP1/achievements) achievement:

> Finish the game firing exactly one bullet. Grenade, crowbar, rocket, and Gravity Gun kills are okay!

I tried getting it, but I'm repeatedly failing in this level. If using shotgun and sub-machine gun against a massive number of zombies in the dark was quite difficult, not using these weapons seems impossible! Half of the time I die, and half of the time Alyx dies. (Before trying to get this achievement, I didn't even know that she could die!)

So... What are the suggestions to pass this map? How to survive long enough? How to get this achievement?

Comment: Clearly dealing with the Zombines is the key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The zombies with **grenades** are the best "weapon" since grenade glow in dark and you can take them with gravity gun packing some chaos...for other tricks check video.

Also Try to remember where the **flares** are,once it gets dark if you manage to find them you can use them to ignite zombies and get yourself some more light on the level.

Comment: I've got the achievement! Thanks! Further suggestions: keep walking around, as being still is easier to get hurt by zombies; keep flashlight on Alyx, so she survives and can kill the zombies; use gravity gun on grenades; use flares when your flashlight runs out of power (and also to set some zombies on fire); and don't get lost in the dark!